# Erro quando eu inicio o ambiente android no react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, gradle

Executei esses passos no meu projeto do react-native:

```
1) Instale o expo (se você chegou até aqui por meio deste curso, já tem o expo instalado e pode pular para o passo 2).

npm install -g expo-cli
2) Verifique as configurações do app.json. Ele deve ter todos as propriedades, abaixo, preenchidas:

{
   "expo": {
    "name": "Nome do Seu Aplicativo",
    "icon": "./caminho/do/icone.png",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "slug": "nome-sem-formatacao",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.suaempresa.nomedoaplicativosemtraco",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.suaempresa.nomedoaplicativosemtraco",
      "versionCode": 1
    }
   }
 }
3) Execute o comando expo eject dentro do projeto e siga o passo a passo no terminal, se houver.

4) Instale o ambiente nativo de Android ou iOS (que você já fez seguindo o artigo acima).

5) Rode o projeto.

Pronto! Instalamos o ambiente nativo de Android ou iOs e rodamos o eject! Muito bem!

Agora, vamos rodar a aplicação com o React Native CLI! Mas antes, precisamos baixar todas as bibliotecas do projeto, então, digite o código no seu terminal (dentro da pasta do projeto):

npm install
Para iniciar o bundle do React Native (esse terminal irá se manter aberto rodando até ser cancelado com Ctrl+C):

npx react-native start
Para rodar a aplicação na plataforma desejada:

npx react-native run-android
npx react-native run-ios
Agora você deve ter o projeto rodando de forma ejetada, sem o expo. Sucesso!´
```

Mas após dar um `npx react-native run-android` o terminal acusou este erro:

```
info Opening the app on Android...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'F:\Documentos\Programa��o USO\forma��o react native\1 - primeiros passos em     react native\orgs-cesta\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'Orgs'.
> Could not read script 'F:\Documentos\Programação USO\formação react native\1 - primeiros     passos em react native\orgs-cesta\node_modules\expo\scripts\autolinking.gradle' as it does not     exist.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 623ms

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'F:\Documentos\Programa��o USO\forma��o react native\1 - primeiros passos em         react native\orgs-cesta\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'Orgs'.
> Could not read script 'F:\Documentos\Programação USO\formação react native\1 - primeiros     passos em react native\orgs-cesta\node_modules\expo\scripts\autolinking.gradle' as it does not     exist.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 623ms

at makeError (F:\Documentos\Programação USO\formação react native\1 - primeiros passos em react native\orgs-cesta\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at F:\Documentos\Programação USO\formação react native\1 - primeiros passos em react native\orgs-cesta\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (F:\Documentos\Programação USO\formação react native\1 - primeiros passos em react native\orgs-cesta\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (F:\Documentos\Programação USO\formação react native\1 - primeiros passos em react native\orgs-cesta\node_modules\@react-native-    community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.